# Trying to get two random samples to have the same matching foreignkey value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am working on a django app that creates random fantasy character names that pull from the following models:

```
    class VillagerFirstNames(models.Model):
        first_name=models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
        race = models.ForeignKey(Race, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.first_name
    class VillagerLastNames(models.Model):
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
        race = models.ForeignKey(Race, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.last_name
```

My issue is arising in my Views. In order to pull a random.sample I have to convert my query to a list like so:

```
    foreign_first = list(VillagerFirstNames.objects.all()
    foreign_first_random = random.sample(foreign_first, 3)
    context["foreign_first"] = foreign_first_random
    foreign_last = list(VillagerLastNames.objects.filter(race__race=foreign_first_random.race))
    context["foreign_last"] = random.sample(foreign_last, 3)
```

Basically, I want the last names pulled to be of the same race as the ones pulled in the first random sample. I'm having trouble figuring this one out, since the way I'm doing it above takes away the "race" attribute from foreign_first_random.

Answer (score 0):

You can do random selection in Race, from there you can select random `VillagerFirstNames` and `VillagerLastNames`. For example:

```
race = Race.objects.all().order_by('?').first()

race_firstname = race.villagerfirstname_set.all().order_by('?').first()
race_lastname = race.villagerlastname_set.all().order_by('?').first()
```

Here [`order_by('?')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) makes the queryset random.

### Update

To pass the values to template, you can try like this:

```
context["foreign_first"] = race.villagerfirstname_set.order_by('?')[:5]
context["foreign_last"] = race.villagerlastname_set.order_by('?')[:5]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Could you tell me how I could pass the first five of each to my template so they line up as a single name?

Comment: @ColinCrusott please see the update section of the answer